# MetaMask - RPC Error: execution reverted {code: -32000, message: 'execution reverted'}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ethereum, web3js, metamask

I'm trying to develop a DApp using React and Solidity using an ERC20 contract, I've deployed my smart contract on Rinkeby and *am* able to interact with it using `name()` and `symbol()`, however, I cannot execute payable functions like `transfer()`, the following error is displayed each time:

```
MetaMask - RPC Error: execution reverted {code: -32000, message: 'execution reverted'}
```

I have tried simply calling `contract.transfer( ... )` and putting quotes around the amount being sent, neither works.

---

JS:

```
await contract.transfer.call(account, 50)
```

---

Sol:

```
interface IERC20 {
    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    // Omitted other functions...

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}
```

```
contract MyCoin is IERC20 {

function transfer(address receiver, uint256 numTokens) public override returns (bool) {
        require(numTokens <= balances[msg.sender]);
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(numTokens);
        balances[receiver] = balances[receiver].add(numTokens);
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, receiver, numTokens);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you haven't marked the transfer() method with "**payable**" modifier. So, you're not calling any payable method, as you asked.

Secondly, when you send any *amount* from a metamask wallet, the contract should have either of these methods, with the logic, in case your contract receives any *amount* :

```
fallback() external payable;
receive() external payable;
```

as then only, your contract knows what to do with incoming *amount*;

---

**Interacting with js:**

also, to send any "amount* and interact with the contract with js. you can use *sendTransaction({})*:

```
await contractInstance.sendTransaction({
        from: accountAddress,
        value: web3.utils.toWei("0.001", "ether")
});
```

Don't do **await contractInstance.receive({})** and call the receive() method directly.

you can see [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/81995) answer, or [this](https://betterprogramming.pub/solidity-0-6-x-features-fallback-and-receive-functions-69895e3ffe) blog for more on this.